# Changes to review pipeline

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

One of the problems I see frequently in reviewing, as well as just reading questions and answers is that the automatic canned responses are frequently not accurate, or there are multiple canned responses (link only, should be comment, etc..) leading to conflicting recommendations.

Another problem is that these comments can unduly influence reviewers.  If you can see the previous automatic comments from other reviewers, then you don't even have to read the answer yourself.. just assume the other reviewer knows what they're doing and "me too" it.

I'd like to suggest one of two possible changes.  The first, would be to not make the automatic review comments visible to other reviewers.  This forces the reviewer to actually read the question/answer and come to their own conclusions.

However, a better solution would be to only post the comments after a consensus has been reached, rather than when the first reviewer clicks the "link only" or whatever review.

I realize that the intent here is to give the user time to improve their question/answer before it gets enough votes to close, but I think a better solution would be to give a grace period after consensus is reached, if after the grace period the answer has not been edited, it gets closed... if it gets edited, then it goes back in the queue (minus the original automated comment).

Perhaps the title can say [Pending close] or something similar...

These automated comments help contribute to a general feeling by users that SO moderators and reviewers are too quick on the delete trigger.  This is exacerbated by the situations where one users clicks "link-only" but 5 others say it's OK, and the answer really is ok.  If my second choice were implemented, the comment would never get added.

Also, the comments almost seem flippant or arrogant in many situations.  I dare say, most users don't even know there is an automated review system, much less that these comments are automatically added.  Their canned nature often makes them a poor fit for the actual situation... However, that's a problem for a different day.

**I think the automated comments as currently implemented are borderline harmful to the review process, as well as harmful to SO's reputation in many cases.  They can be handled in a better way.**

Comment: Ugh, so much this. Repeat after me: **you don't need to pile on review comments when others have already left them earlier.**

Comment: **You don't need to pile on review comments when others have already left them earlier.**

Comment: ... wait a minute.

Comment: @BoltClock - **You don't need to pile on review comments when others have already left them earlier.**

Comment: @BoltClock: I thought the review system prevented the same comment being added twice, has that changed recently?

Comment: @Qantas 94 Heavy: Not sure. It could be people posting from several different review queues. Or people just being really irritating and manually typing the comments.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - I meant you might get one person marking it as "Link only" and another as "Should be a comment", each would generate a different comment with different text.

Comment: Agreed EXCEPT for the part about the grace period. Closure _is_ the grace period. Problems need to get fixed ASAP; allowing answers before cleanup usually just creates a bigger mess.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - Well, I am trying to deal with the concept that flagging an automated comment immediately gives the asker time to modify the question before it is closed.  By changing the process as I suggest, we remove that feature..  Then again, maybe that's a good thing as apparently, you can game the system by deleting your post and undeleting it, causing it to be removed from the review queue.